# SendKeys is adding the new text to the old text so how do I replace the existing text

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I am in no way a programmer, I am just trying to Automate a Chrome report in my Excel workbook.

I am using VBA Selenium and I need to send a date to a text field. I have used `FindElementByXPath` and `FindElementByName` and both are working.

```
obj.FindElementByName("filter_date_start_sold").Click – works
obj.FindElementByName("filter_date_start_sold").Clear – works
obj.FindElementByName("filter_date_start_sold").SendKeys ("01/08/2018").
```

This works but it adds the new date to the date that was already listed in the Text Field so it become `01/08/202001/08/2018`

I have tried to use `.SendKeys` (Keys.Backspace) but the Back Space function will not do anything.

```
Sub ChromeAutoSYD()

Dim obj As New WebDriver
obj.Start "chrome", ""

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Obj.Get "I am sorry  I cannot list the actual URL as it is a company DB Site"

'The Sheet reference is my login details and this all works well
obj.FindElementByName("username").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D20").Value)
obj.FindElementByName("password").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D21").Value)
obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/button").Click

obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/input").SendKeys("01082018").Value

 obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/button").Click
 
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post some code so I can test

Comment: Hi Mike67, thanks for looking at this, not sure how I should post Code but I will give it a try.

Comment: Just edit your post and add the code to the text. Use the {} button to format text as code to make it look better.

Comment: did you try with clear() method you can clear first and then  sendkeys to the field?

Comment: Hi Justin,
Yes I did and the Clear method worked as well, but when I send the new date text the Field seems to populate again first and the new text is added to the last. I think there may be some form of control in the text field of this page that make sit populate every time the focus comes on it.